# applescript for adobe reader to save as text

Tags: applescript

Who can tell me why I'm getting this error:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item \"Text…\" of menu item \"Save As\" of menu \"File\" of menu bar 1 of process \"Adobe Reader\"." number -1728 from menu item "Text…" of menu item "Save As" of menu "File" of menu bar 1 of process "Adobe Reader"
```

for this code:

```
tell application "Adobe Reader"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Reader"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu "File"
                tell menu item "Save As"
                    click menu item "Text…"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
activate application "Adobe Reader"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Reader"
        click menu item "Text..." of menu 1 of menu item "Save As" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Any idea why FileMaker still doesn't like the click command but script editor does?